# Feast from the side of girl's family (marriage)

Tags: nikah

In marriage there's a walima (feast) from the side of boy's family and this is sunnah, and there's nothing like this from the girl's family, right? So is it permissible for girl's family to do things like this( like feast) in marriage?

Answer (score 1):

if any such feast from the bride's side is offered without any pressure eg. social, peer, or any other then there is no harm in entertaining family, relatives, friends, or any human as sadaqah which is promoted as appraisable culture in Islam as well!

> ‘Abdullah ibn ‘Amr(Radiyallahu Anhu) said, “A man asked the Prophet(Peace be upon him), ‘Which aspect of Islam is best?‘
>
> He said, ‘FEEDING PEOPLE and greeting those you know and those you do not know.'”►{Sahih Bukhari,Kitab Al-Iman,Hadith #12}

[image]

Allah knows the best!

Comment: So if my neighbour has invited me in this marriage feast, should I go. Note that this marriage feast is from bride's family.

Comment: But this culture was not in the time of prophet Muhammad pbuh, I mean the culture of feeding others on marriage day from the side of girl's family, so is it still permissible to go in these feasts?

Comment: @Anonymous We need to differentiate between religious and cultural practices. If the bride's side wants to offer a wedding reception on their own accord & they have the financial needs to do so (without taking loan), then inshallah it is fine. There are many cultural rituals that are not part of Islam. If we don't mix the two, there is no harm as long as the Hudud of Shariah are observed.